# View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN doesn't work on HUAWEI P20

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar, huawei-mobile-services

I am having and issue where activity/fragment has to enter in full screen mode (if user expands an view).
This actually works on (almost) all devices by using following code:

```
 decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But, somehow, it is not the case with HUAWEI P20. It **hides the status bar**, but there is a **blank space**, and bottom content is overlapped by bottom navigation. 
On other devices, it is shown properly (full screen, no blank space).
I tried using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` wherever I could but nothing could fix this.

EDIT:
I actually hide Toolbar as well, but that part works as expected on all devices (including Huawei P20). The **only** problem is with **status bar** on Huawei P20.

Any suggestions?

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

May be you forgot to add the two extra lines.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

You can use your `manifest.xml`, adding a theme to your target activity.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Or, you can set programmatically.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
else
{
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
}
```

For more info, read android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status).

Comment: Please, read my question more carefully. I am not sure if ActionBar/Toolbar has to do anything with this. 
We actually hide Toolbar as well. 
As I said, this works on all devices except Huawei P20

Comment: @Glimpse did you found a solution ? I am also discovering just Huawei is not working...

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution. Not working on this issue anymore